# Pathologic insertion times

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, database-performance

I have a SQL query something like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (col1, col2,...) 
    SELECT col1, col2,... 
    FROM @tempTable
```

There are only a few (5 or less) rows in the temp table and it takes about 2 milliseconds to insert the data. So far so good.

But, once in few dozen calls, it takes about 500 milliseconds to execute. It is not repeatable, if I delete last rows and insert the very same data the same way again, it is 2 milliseconds as expected.

250x random slowdown seems too extreme for any explanation I can imagine. The server is rather idle and has plenty of memory, db is on SSD. What puzzles me most is, that not only does it take longer. Also the CPU usage increases from 2ms to 500ms. As the execution plan is still the same and the inserted data are exactly the same, what suddenly takes 250x more work? Also, I/O reads increase from cca 200 to cca 6000. I would be glad for any ideas how to fix the performance unstability.

Comment: That seems like a long time.  But it is probably doing "cleanup" stuff like dealing with page splits and indexes and so on.

Comment: SOMETHING is off - I can tell you that at least it is possible to NOT have this behavior. Query plan, and off to PasteThePlan - https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Is "Auto Close" in the database properties set to False?

Comment: @TomTom I can not reproduce the issue on will, so I can provide only plan for working situation. There is some logic in the triggers, so the plan is not trivial https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1vT3Wg2U

Comment: @AndrewMorton "Auto Close" is set to False

Comment: Have you considered using `#tempTable` instead of `@tempTable`? Have you checked compile times ([Plan Explorer](https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer) will show you this, and will also easily show you where the extra reads happened), or checked for blocking or resource usage, or compared any potential differences in plans between executions?

Comment: (Also, I wouldn't really consider 500ms "250x more work" - something caused a very minor delay, it wasn't 250x more expensive.)

Comment: Triggers. I would start looking there. I have seen triggers that did web service calls back when I was working at MS support - and people wondered why the inserts took long ;) Triggers manipulating OTHER data may also result in delays due to locking (waiting for a lock))

Comment: the execution plan you posted has 26 plans. Have you definitively identified which one(s) take longer?

Comment: @MartinSmith The problem is, how to get plan of the situation that takes long when it is not repeatable. I get the plan when it works well. I would look if there is a way to get actual execution plan from the application that calls the stored procedure.

Comment: you can look in `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` to see which of those plans have high max values

Comment: @AaronBertrand with option(recompile) it takes about 25ms, so recompile does not seem to be the problem. And with calling the same stored proc there should not be recompilation at all which seems to be the case. There is no extra row in the sys.dm_exec_query_stats for the bad case.

Comment: there wouldn't be expected to be an extra row. but it tells you the max CPU time, reads etc. so which of those 26 plans have wide variance for these?

Comment: @MartinSmith I did not realize that, thank you. This seems to be the tool I was looking for. I would accept it as an answer actually. But while I have statistics from wednesday on, statistics for this query seem to get wiped yesterday evening, I did not know that. I would have to check everything on monday with new production data. Now I should get somewhere, thank you again.

Comment: Compilation time is not a constant, predictable thing. I was merely trying to point out one of the things that _could_ factor into runtime variance. Saying `option (recompile)` didn't cause a variance "_this time_" ignores that you're currently having a hard time reproducing bad variance _in any case_.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thank you for the clarification, with new data it seems you are right. `creation_time` in `dm_exec_query_stats` keeps updated and that should mean recompilation. But I would have to study more to be sure about that, it is new for me and still quite confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MartinSmith particulary, the mystery is mostly revealed. @TomTom was right with triggers and @AaronBertrand with compilation. The problem is

> Triggers recompilation

There are recompile events of triggers in trace log corresponding with the long times execution of insertion. The compilation causes both CPU and IO increase. While the `option (recompile)` in the stored procedure induces about 25ms delay, recompilation of the triggers on the table is a whole different story and this is what the server is doing for half of a second. The execution plan is not evicted from cache, so the memory pressuse is not likely the reason, presumably it gets recompiled for performace reasons. What makes the optimizer think that it is a good idea would be subject of further research.